# How to configure L2TP Client on Juniper SRX?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, l2tp

I have an Juniper SRX 100, running JunOS 12.1X46-D66.

I would like to use it to route all Internet traffic through an L2TP tunnel to an ISP called Andrews and Arnold, who offer this as a service. This is not an encrypted L2TP or L2TP over IPsec, it is simple L2TPv2 over UDP.

After hours of Googling, I have found information about setting up a Juniper MX series as an L2TP LNS but nothing about setting up a SRX as a client.

I am not quite sure where to start. I have looked into:

- Configure a pp0 PPP interface to use a UDP tunnel
- Change the transport/encryption for an IPSec VPN
- Setting options on the st0 tunnel interface

But so far failed to find a likely looking option or examples.

Does anyone know how to configure a Juniper SRX as an L2TPv2 client?

Thanks,

nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/L2TP-connection-on-SRX210/td-p/280803), Juniper SRX cannot act as L2TP client.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it is harder to verify that something is unsupported, than supported.